# Image uploading after crop image using jquery rain codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'am using a plugin for cropping the uploading image. The plugin link is: 
http://www.jqueryrain.com/?7VoW4dx3

I'm using the framework codeigniter and trying to save the cropped image. But I can only save the original image.

Kindly help me to save the cropped image or give me any suggestions to do this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin places the cropped image into a `div` having class `cropped` as row image data.
for example : -

```
<div class="cropped">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM">
</div>
```

you have to retrieve this data inside image src and handle it at php side.

if  you get data in string like

```
   $str="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAM";
```

create a file at you preferred location

```
 $file ='/TH-' . date("Y-m-d", time()) . '-' . str_replace(' ', '', microtime()) . '.png'; 
 $imgData = base64_decode(stripslashes(substr($str, 22)));
 $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
 fwrite($fp, $imgData);
 fclose($fp);
```